# Highlight a row until all cells are filled

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, formula

I am using conditional formatting to highlight a row if a cell has something entered and will remain highlighted until all cells in that row are filled.

`=COUNTA($B$2:$E$1)>0`

*Conditional format if true changes the cell interior to Yellow `(B1:E1)`
For each cell in the `COUNTA`, I use conditional formatting to change the cell to white if `No Blanks`.

This is making my conditional formatting cue huge. For each line, there is a conditional format to change to yellow with `COUNTA`, then each cell has a conditional format to change it to white when it has any data entered.

My question is; is there a better way to accomplish this without conditional formatting?
My goal is to have the sheet - each row - white. If any data is entered into any cell, it will highlight the entire row in yellow until every cell in that row is filled out making the entire row white again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One formula makes it!
Keeping in mind you have headers in row 1, the region starts at row 2

```
=AND(COUNTA($B2:$E2)>0;COUNTA($B2:$E2)<4)

=$B$2:$E$35
```

[image]

[image]